# Showing $f(x)=g(x^{p^a})$ over field of (prime) characteristic $p>0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Let $f$ be a non-constant irreducible polynomial over  a field $F$ of (prime) characteristic $p>0$. I need to prove that $f$ can be presented as:
$f(x)=g(x^{p^a})$, where $g$ is irreducible over $F$ and separable.

So far I know that if $f$ has multiple roots, $f$ can be presented as $h(x^p)$,  but I can't deduce that $h(x)$ is separable.

Does anyone have a direction?
Thanks.

Comment: If $f=h(x^p)$ is irreducible, then surely $h$ must be irreducible, isn't it? If $h$ isn't separable, you can just try again for $h$, and prove that it must stop at  some point.

Comment: ok. and what about the case f doesn't have multiple roots?

Comment: If it aint got multiple roots (in the algebraic closure) then its separable.

Comment: understood,thanks a lot.